# Uikit Notification finish then navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, typescript, getuikit

I want to popup a notification then navigate to the login page.

```
UIkit.notification({message: 'no access, please login again', status: 'danger'});
this.router.navigateByUrl('login'); // angular navigation by url
```

However it popups the message and navigate to the login page at the same time. What I want is to wait the notification closed then doing the navigation.

If we only have the first line code for the notification, the popup window will vanish in 5 seconds by default. In my code there are two lines, the popup window vanishes quickly then running the second line code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure UIkit. Notification component triggers `close` [event](https://getuikit.com/docs/notification#events) when closed, which you can use for custom function. To run the function only on the specific error notification, you can add your own custom class (`login-error` in my example).

```js
UIkit.notification({
  message: 'no access, please login again',
  status: 'danger login-error'
});


UIkit.util.on('.login-error', 'close', function() {
  console.log('Notification closed');
  //this.router.navigateByUrl('login'); // angular navigation by url
});
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.4/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.4/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.5.4/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you delay some time to log after the notification closed?

Comment: you can use `setTimeout`